# GetComboBoxInfo returning false

Tags: c++, mfc

I have a derived class from `CComboBox` and I want to subclass the `CEdit` and `CListCtrl` with my derived classes.

For some reason, when I call the function `GetComboBoxInfo`, it's returning false.

Here's how I call my function :

```
PCOMBOBOXINFO pcbi;
BOOL verif;
verif = GetComboBoxInfo(pcbi);
```

I've tried with `this->GetComboBoxInfo(pcbi)`, but still nothing.

I've tried to derive my class from `CComboBoxEx` and use the `GetEditCtrl()` function, but nothing as well.

I've used the function `GetLastError()` to trap the error message and it gives me 87, which is `ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER`, but I don't understand why.

Thx.

Comment: If that version of `GetComboBoxInfo` works the same as the Windows API `GetComboBoxInfo`, you must set the `cbSize` member of the `PCCOMBOBOXINFO`.  [See the documentation here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getcomboboxinfo)

Comment: `PCCOMBOBOXINFO` is a pointer declaration. Use `CCOMBOBOXINFO cbi = {0};` instead (without the `P`) and initialize `cbi.cbSize = sizeof(CCOMBOBOXINFO);`

Comment: You should __never__ use the Windows `P...` types in a declaration, it's confusing as you have noticed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One obvious error is that you are sending an uninitialized pointer to the `GetComboBoxInfo` function.

Never send an uninitialized pointer to any function, unless that function takes a reference to that pointer and does the initialization / setting itself inside the function.

As the comment suggested, you need to use a non-pointer type, as `PCOMBOBOXINFO` is a pointer declaration.  The type to use is [`COMBOBOXINFO`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/ns-winuser-tagcomboboxinfo):

```
COMBOBOXINFO cbi {};  // set everything to 0
cbi.size = sizeof(COMBOBOXINFO); // set the size, as per the documentation
BOOL verif;
verif = GetComboBoxInfo(&cbi);  // pass the address
```

[See the documentation on GetComboBoxInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getcomboboxinfo)

Comment: That's it ! Thank you :)